# Use videojs-vr in Vuejs component

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, video.js

I am trying to use the [videojs-vr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-vr), which I install via npm, in a Vuejs component.  And got an error:

```
TypeError: videojs is not a function
at VueComponent.mounted (VR.vue?d2da:23)
at callHook (vue.esm.js?65d7:2701)
at Object.insert (vue.esm.js?65d7:3588)
at invokeInsertHook (vue.esm.js?65d7:5541)
at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (vue.esm.js?65d7:5744)
at VueComponent.Vue._update (vue.esm.js?65d7:2460)
```

I tried, to *import* or *require* the library. There must be something wrong with the way I use the npm library.  Please help.

```
<template>
  <div class="videojs-vr" style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
    <video id="videojs-vr-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls>
      <source src="./static/videos/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
var videojs = require('videojs-vr');
// import videojs from 'videojs-vr';

export default {
  name: 'videojs-vr',
  mounted() {
    var player = videojs('videojs-vr-player');
    player.mediainfo = player.mediainfo || {};
    player.mediainfo.projection = '360';
    // AUTO is the default and looks at mediainfo
    player.vr({projection: 'AUTO', debug: true, forceCardboard: false});
  },   
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first require the `video.js` module and set that reference as the `videojs` variable. Then, you simply require the `videojs-vr` module without setting it to any variable.

[Here's the example from the documentation:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-vr)

> ```
> var videojs = require('video.js');
>
> // The actual plugin function is exported by this module, but it is also
> // attached to the `Player.prototype`; so, there is no need to assign it
> // to a variable.
> require('videojs-vr');
>
> var player = videojs('my-video');
>
> player.vr({projection: '360'});
> ```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  :)  This is when copy and paste really failed.